# How to rewrite code to optionals?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type

In my current job we are rewriting some code to Java 8.
If you have code like this:

```
if(getApi() != null && getApi().getUser() != null 
     && getApi().getUser().getCurrentTask() != null)  
{
   getApi().getUser().getCurrentTask().pause();
}
```

you can simply rewrite it to

```
Optional.ofNullable(this.getApi())
.map(Api::getUser)
.map(User::getCurrentTask)
.ifPresent(Task::pause);
```

without changing code behaviour.
 but what if something in the middle can throw NPE because it is not checked to null?

for example:

```
if(getApi() != null && getApi().getUser() != null 
     && getApi().hasTasks())  
{
   getApi().getMasterUser(getApi().getUser()) //<- npe can be here
     .getCurrentTask().pause();
}
```

what is the best way to rewrite code like this using optionals?(it should work exactly the same and throw npe when `getMasterUser(...)` returns null)

**UPD**
second example:

```
if(getApi()!=null && getApi.getUser() != null)
{
   if(getApi().getUser().getDepartment().getBoss() != null)// <- nre if department is null
     {
        getApi().getUser().getDepartment().getBoss().somefunc();
     }
 }
```

it has nullchecks for api, user, boss, but not department. how can it be made using optionals?

Comment: The first line of code has a bitwise AND, is that correct?

Comment: Of course it was mistake @Mike

Comment: Shouldn't `Optional.ofNullable(this::getApi)` be `Optional.ofNullable(this.getApi())` instead?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it works the same, but method reference is one symbol shorter :)

Comment: It is by no means the same. `Optional.ofNullable(this::getApi)` doesn't even compile. To fix it, you'd need an explicit cast: `Optional.ofNullable((Supplier<Api>) this::getApi)`, and if the actual `getApi()` method returned `null`, `Optional.ofNullable(this.getApi())` would return `false`, while `Optional.ofNullable((Supplier<Api>) this::getApi)` would always return `true`, no matter the method's implementation.

Comment: Btw, despite this detail, this is an excellent question ;)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thanks for info. Guides I used to follow seem to lie a little :)

Comment: Regarding the question, you could use `orElseThrow()` method.

Comment: orElseThrow() unwraps optional, so yo have to wrap it back into optional after and so makes code ugly imho @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner especially when there is more than one time you have to check it

Comment: @maxpovver You're correct. That's what happens when you're not near a PC ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(getApi() != null && getApi().getUser() != null) {
    if(getApi().getUser().getDepartment().getBoss() != null) {
        getApi().getUser().getDepartment().getBoss().somefunc();
    }
}
```

One way of writing this with optionals is:

```
Optional.ofNullable(this.getApi())
    .map(Api::getUser)
    .map(user -> Objects.requireNonNull(user.getDepartment()))
    .map(Department::getBoss)
    .ifPresent(Boss::somefunc);
```

But this is error-prone because it requires the client to keep track of what is and isn't optional. A better way would be to make the api itself return an optional instead of a nullable value. Then the client code is:

```
this.getApi()
    .flatMap(Api::getUser)
    .map(user -> user.getDepartment().getBoss())
    .ifPresent(Boss::somefunc));
```

This would make it clearer in the api which values should be optional and make it a compile-time error to not handle them.

```
if(getApi() != null && getApi().getUser() != null && getApi().hasTasks()) {
    getApi().getMasterUser(getApi().getUser()).getCurrentTask().pause();
}
```

Here, you need access to `api` and `user` at the same time so you probably need to nest the lambdas:

```
getApi().filter(Api::hasTasks).ifPresent(api -> {
    api.getUser().ifPresent(user -> {
        api.getMasterUser(user).getCurrentTask().ifPresent(Task::pause);
    });
});
```

Comment: The second one looks quite close to what I need, but it requires to rewrite legacy code and all code that uses these functions, which is usually impossible. So there is noting like `.mapStrict(map_func, error_func)` that calls `error_func` if `map_func` was called and returned null?

Comment: @maxpovver I think the closest you get is: `map(user -> Objects.requireNonNull(user.getDepartment()))`.

Comment: thanks. plz add code from comment to the answer so I can accept it. It's still not perfect because monad should check it, not the function that is applied to monad, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

For the second example (applicable to first as well), this is shorter and about as obvious as the longer version:

```
Optional.ofNullable(getApi())
.map(Api::getUser)
.flatMap(u -> Optional.ofNullable(u.getDepartment().getBoss()))
.ifPresent(Boss::somefunc);
```

It also relies on less API.

I would additionally like to comment on your "this breaks the monad pattern"—nothing here (including your solutions) breaks the monad pattern. It is fully expressible in terms of `return` and `>>=`. If anything, it is the `ifPresent` call which breaks it because it implies side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer for the first example is

```
Optional.ofNullable(getApi())
.filter(Api::hasTasks)
.map(Api::getUser)
.map(u -> Objects.requireNonNull(getApi().getMasterUser(u)))//api won't be null here so no need to check it
.map(MasterUser::getCurrentTask)
.ifPresent(Task::pause);
```

and for second example:

```
Optional.ofNullable(getApi())
.map(Api::getUser)
.map(u -> Objects.requireNonNull(u.getDepartment()))
.map(Department::getBoss)
.ifPresent(Boss::somefunc);
```

So you have to change `.map(class::func)` to `.map(o -> Objects.requireNonNull(o.func()))` to make it throw NRE when needed.

It breaks monad pattern of course, but it is still better than no any solution

Correct me if I am wrong please.